# onchange calculations for dynamic form inputs using PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The scenario:

I'm allowing a user to select a number of pizzas, they then go to a page where they can choose different options for each pizza. The idea is that as they change an option for a pizza the results are shown in a results div for that pizza with the price. If the user has chosen 3 pizzas there will be lots of options with three divs to show the results for each, and a grand total div.

I have successfully looped through and created the option boxes, but I am struggling to see the best way to get the selections of the dynamic form values so I can do calculations and run some ajax to populate the result divs.

This is the generated forms(though they could probably all go into one form)

```
<?php 
    $boxNum = 0; ///to append to form input id names
    ///start loop
    foreach(loops through array){///start loop
        $theid =  ///this successfully assigns the id
        $pizzaname =  /// this successfully assigns the pizza name              
?>
<div  id="pizza_option_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  >
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="theid_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  id="theid_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  type="text" value="<?php echo $theid; ?>" class="bk" >
        <input name=" pizzaname _<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  id=" pizzaname _<?php echo $boxNum; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $pizzaname?>" class="bk">
        <select name="sizes_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  id="sizes_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  class="bk"> 
            <?php  avaliable_sizes($id);  ///fuction to get available sizes ?>
        </select>

        <select name="topping_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  id="topping_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  class="bk"> 
            <?php  avaliable_toppings($id);  ///fuction to get available toppings ?>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>  
<?php  $boxNum ++;  } // end of loop ?>

<div  id="pizza_results_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  >
    Display  selection choices and cost for  pizza
</div>

<div  id="grand_total_for_pizzas"  >
    Display  total of all pizzas
</div>
```

I have found it difficult to find resources that, a cover both dynamic form input values and event trigger when a form input has been changed.

You will see from my pseudo code that I have appended a unique `id` to the input `ID` as this I am thinking this can be used to identify a set of pizza inputs.
If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful. I only require guidance on identifying when there is a change on one of the values for a pizza, not on any calculations or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Ok,  after a little more digging around I found a solution:

by adding an event to the inputs:

```
onchange="calc(this)"
```

I can append the id I assigned to the input ID and get the values of the other elements

```
function calc(elem) {
//just get the number
    var id = $(elem).attr("id").match(/\d+$/);
//append the id to the element ID
    alert($('#pizzaname_'+id).val());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [**event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created elements.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now **or are added in the future**.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // to listen for value changes of the element with class 'bk':
    // (event is attached to the document) 
    $(document).on('change', '.bk', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        // do stuff when value has been changed...
    });

    // attach event to other element (must be one of the parents of the inputs)
    $('#some_parent_element').on('change', '.bk', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        // do stuff when value has been changed...
    });

})
```

I would also add a `data-id` attribute to each input, so that you can easily get the id:

```
<select data-id="<?php echo $boxNum; ?>" name="sizes_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  id="sizes_<?php echo $boxNum; ?>"  class="bk">
```

And then in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.bk', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var pizza_name = $('pizzaname_'+id).val();
});
```

Comment: works well,  thank you for taking the time to answer